# Is it possible to use Thread Scoped Lifestyle in method with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have the following code:

```
public class TempForm : Form
{
    private readonly IGoogleAuth _googleAuth;
    private readonly IComAssistant _comAssistant;

    public TempForm(IGoogleAuth googleAuth, IComAssistant comAssistant)
    {
        _googleAuth = googleAuth;
        _comAssistant = comAssistant;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var excelThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            //NEED NEW INSTANCE OF EXCEL_APP PER THREAD
            using (IExcelApp excel = new ExcelApp(_comAssistant))
            {
                //Do stuff with excel.
                excel.CreateWorkBook();
                //...
            }
        });

        excelThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        excelThread.Start();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        //Initialize form components
    }
}
```

I have no problems with `IGoogleAuth` or `IComAssistant` services, because they are registered as `Singletone` in container an I injected them in form constructor.

But in `ButtonClick` method I need the new instance of `ExcelApp` per each new thread.

I can do it is such way:

```
using (ThreadScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container)) {
    var excel = container.GetInstance<IExcelApp>();
}
```

But in this way I need to pass `container` which declared in `Program.cs` into my `TempForm` form.

Is it possible to achive such behavior without passing container itself?

If no - what is the best practices to use `container` instance in several places.
We need to make it as singleton, or put them in own `ServiceLocator` implementation?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be using ServiceLocator here. You should inject all services all the time and then allow the IoC container to resolve them in the constructor, not get instances using service locator.

Comment: Bear in mind that a thread scoped instance consumed by a singleton will not get released and re-resolved so it will act like a singleton regardless. If your mixing scopes like this, you need to be very careful how you use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to achive such behavior without passing container itself?

Yes, it's certainly possible. The trick is extract this logic out of your Form component into its own component. In other words, you create an [Aggregate Service](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/). For instance:

```
public class TempForm : Form
{
    private readonly IGoogleAuth _googleAuth;
    private readonly IExcelExporter _exporter;

    public TempForm(IGoogleAuth googleAuth, IExcelExporter exporter)
    {
        _googleAuth = googleAuth;
        _exporter = exporter;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _exporter.Export(...);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        //Initialize form components
    }
}
```

Here we extract all the code related to generating the excel document out of the Form, into its own component.

Such implementation might look as follows:

```
public class ExcelExporter : IExcelExporter
{
    private readonly IComAssistant _comAssistant;

    public ExcelExporter(IComAssistant comAssistant)
    {
        _comAssistant = comAssistant;
    }

    private void Export(...)
    {
        //NEED NEW INSTANCE OF EXCEL_APP PER THREAD
        using (IExcelApp excel = new ExcelApp(_comAssistant))
        {
            //Do stuff with excel.
            excel.CreateWorkBook();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how this component itself has no notion of threading. Threading is a concern that this component should not be responsible of. Leaving this out of this class makes the class simpler to understand and easier to test.

That does mean however that we will have to implement this threading logic somewhere. We however want to leave this out of the Form and out of the `ExcelExporter`. And when doing this, we need a reference to the `Container`.

Every piece of code that requires access to the `Container` should be centralized in the application's start-up code, a.k.a. the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

An effective approach to add this threading behavior to our new `ExcelExporter` component is by making use of a proxy around `IExcelExporter`:

```
public class BackgroundExcelExporterProxy : IExcelExporter
{
    private readonly Container _container;
    private readonly Func<IExcelExporter> _excelExporterFactory;

    public ExcelExporter(
        Container container, Func<IExcelExporter> excelExporterFactory)
    {
        _container = container;;
        _excelExporterFactory = excelExporterFactory;
    }

    private void Export(...)
    {
        var excelThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            using (ThreadScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container)) 
            {
                var exporter = _excelExporterFactory();
                exporter.Export(...);
            }
        });

        excelThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        excelThread.Start();
    }
}
```

This class takes a dependency on `Container`. When `Export` is called, it will start a new `Thread` and within that thread it will start a new Thread Scope. Within that thread scope it will resolve a new `IExporter` with its dependencies.

When this class is registered in Simple Injector using the `RegisterDecorator` method (as far as Simple Injector is concerned, this is a decorator), Simple Injector will natively understand the `Func<IExcelExporter>` dependency and will understand that this delegate should resolve an instance of the decorated instance (`ExcelExporter` in your case).

We can register this as follows:

```
container.Register<IExcelExporter, ExcelExporter>();
container.RegisterDecorator<IExcelExporter, BackgroundExcelExporterProxy>(
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

This will result in the following object graph:

```
new TempForm(
    MyGoogleAuth(...),
    new BackgroundExcelExporterProxy(
        container,
        () => new ExcelExporter(new MyComAssistant(...))));
```

> We need to make it as singleton, or put them in own ServiceLocator implementation?

You might think that the `BackgroundExcelExporterProxy` has a Service Locator, but as long as this class resides *inside* the *Composition Root*, it's not a Service Locator, as explained [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/).

Comment: Thanks for great explanation! That's exactly what I need.